# Python index error: list index out of range value table findall

Tags: python, indexing

I'm a beginner and I keep receiving one error on python 2.7.
The code its like this:

```
Value = table.findAll('td')[1].text.split(' ')[0].strip()
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you please describe what you are exactly doing and what is error you are encountering?

Comment: Hi, it would be a great help to us if 1. You can specify what is the error message 2. What is the expected output 3. What is the input. Also use Python 3, Python 2 is not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be either that you don't have td's in the table object or that the test not contains spaces ' '. 
Probably the spaces issue, you can try

```
value = table.findAll('td')[1].text
value = value.split(' ')[0].strip() if value.count(' ') > 0 else value
```

This code will make the split only if the text contains spaces.